# How do I raise an event in FakeItEasy for an event based on a custom delegate?

Tags: c#, mocking, fakeiteasy

The application I am testing is full of events based on custom delegates, such as this:

```
public delegate void NameChangedHandler(string name);
public event NameChanged OnNameChanged;
...
public void ChangeYourName(string newName)
{
    if( NameChanged != null )
        NameChanged(newName);
}
```

I want to mock out the class producing these events and raise these events to the class under test.

I know that FakeItEasy can use `Raise.With()` for raising events with the traditional event signatures of  `MyHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)` or `MyHandler(EventArgs e)`, but I don't know what to do in my situation.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have run into the exact same thing just today.  Can someone help here?

Comment: I believe the answer is that FakeItEasy cannot do this.  My solution was to refactor my event to take EventArgs.

Comment: There is an issue raised for this https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/issues/30

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of [FakeItEasy 2.0.0](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/releases/tag/2.0.0), this is now possible.

The [Raising Events documentation topic](http://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/raising-events/) has the full story, but the gist is that you'd use

```
fake.OnNameChanged += Raise.With<NameChanged>(newName);
```

As always, the event must be virtual.

Answer (score 0):

You could always make `ChangeYourName` virtual and replace the method.

```
A.CallsTo(()=>fakeClass.ChangeyourName(A<string>._)).Invokes((x)=>invokeMockEvent(x));
```

If that isn't what you wanted, I suppose if `ChangeYourName` is public you could just create your fake class

```
var class = new Class();
class.OnNameChanged += (x)=>
{
    Assert.AreEqual(x,"tim");
};

class.ChangeYourName("tim");
```